# TicTacToe how to reset containerView content?

Tags: ios, swift

I need some help over here. I try to learn... some things and practice but i'm not able to manage that function.

**I have this function creating the container view:**

```
    func createGameView() {
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: self.screenHeight * 0.4,
                                 width: screenWidth,
                                 height: screenHeight * 0.6)

    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.13, blue:0.00, alpha:1)
    self.view.addSubview(containerView)
```

**After that I have a function who will populate the container view with 9 squares**

```
    func createGridView( _ container : UIView) {

    let buttonWidth = container.frame.size.width / 3

    let buttonHeight = container.frame.size.height / 3

    for i in [0,1,2] {
        for j in 0...2 {
        let button = UIButton(frame:
        CGRect( x : buttonWidth * CGFloat (i),
                y :buttonHeight * CGFloat (j),
                width : buttonWidth,
                height : buttonHeight ))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.1, green: 0.89, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1)
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        container.addSubview(button)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.addGameValue(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.tag = i + 3 * j
            self.gameButtons.append(button)
      }
    }
}
```

**And I have a button called RESET**

```
    var resetButton = UIButton(frame:
        CGRect(x: Double(containerView.frame.size.width  - 100),
               y: Double(containerView.frame.size.height - 60),
               width: 60,
               height: 40.0)
        )

    resetButton.setTitle ("Reset", for: UIControlState.normal)
    resetButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
    resetButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .highlighted)
    resetButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    resetButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    resetButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    resetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.resetGame), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    containerView.addSubview(resetButton)
```

**This is where i got a problem :(**

```
func resetGame (sender: UIButton) {  
    // .addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.createGameView), for: .touchUpInside)
   print(" reset me ")
   // .addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.resetGame), for: .touchUpInside)

}
```

**Anyone can tell me why none of those are not working to reset the value ? Is a tic tac toe game, and after  put some x and 0 i want to restore the gridView to intial state. Got no ideea how to do it.**

Comment: so is reset me not being printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have all of the buttons that you need added to the view after `createGridView` is called, so on reset all you have to do is reset the button state, clear any scores/points and your ready to start again.

```
func resetGame() {
   // reset any scores, colors etc
   for button in self.gameButtons {
       button.setTitle ("", for: UIControlState.normal)
       button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.1, green: 0.89, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, that func reset the buttons... problem is i'm not able after that to play the game again.

Comment: I dont know what else you have in your game to reset? you have a target action GameViewController.addGameValue(sender:), i'm guessing that it updates a score, so i put in comment in code above, reset scores etc. I can't guess at what other code you have unless you show it

Comment: I've updated the answer so that it also resets the background colour of the buttons too. The only thing that changes during the game is changing of the button title and background colour, so your reset function just sets them back to their original state

Comment: Ok. Thanks ! Great. Now i have to write the code inside this func to start the game again.

Comment: Solved. Calling the self.createGameView() inside resetGame